# Why wp_query loop still considers hidden categories and 'post__not_in' in pagination?

Tags: php, loops, pagination, wordpress

I have three loops on same page.

1. The first loop displays the most recent post of category "highlight".
2. The second loop displays others posts of this same category in chronological order.
3. The third loop displays all the posts, except the posts in others loops.

All works fine, but in pagination (pagenavi), the max_num_pages considers all the posts, ignoring criterias like 'post__not_in' or 'cat'.

If I use this loop, the last page of pagenavi stills in blank (counts hidden posts yet, but don't shows them):

```
if ($loop3->have_posts()) : while ($loop3->have_posts()) : $loop3->the_post();
```

And If I use this loop (loop 3), the last page of pagenavi shows the "hidden" posts:

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

How to force the wp_query loop to exclude the hidden posts of the max_num_pages count?

```
//loop 1

  <?php
  $loop1 = new WP_query(array(
  'category_name' => 'highlight',
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  ));
  if($loop1->have_posts()) : $firstPosts = array(); while($loop1->have_posts()) : $loop1->the_post();
  $firstPosts[] = $post->ID;
  ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

  <?php endif; ?>

//loop 2

  <?php
  $loop2 = new WP_query(array(
  'post__not_in' => $firstPosts,
  'category_name' => 'highlight',
  'posts_per_page' => 2,
  ));
  if($loop2->have_posts()) : while($loop2->have_posts()) : $loop2->the_post();
  $firstPosts[] = $post->ID;
  ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

  <?php endif; ?>

//loop 3

  <?php
  $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'paged' => $paged,
  'post__not_in' => $firstPosts,
  'cat' => -23,
  );
  $loop3 = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ($loop3->have_posts()) : while ($loop3->have_posts()) : $loop3->the_post();
  ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

  <?php else:  ?>

  <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>

  <?php endif; ?>

//other stuff

//pagenavi

  <?php wp_pagenavi("", "", array(
    'query' => $loop3,
    'first_text' => 'lorem ipsum',
    'last_text' => 'lorem ipsum',
  )); ?>
```

Comment: Where in your code are you including the pager?

Comment: Hi! I updated the code in main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using WP-PageNavi, there is a special way to use it with custom queries. For example:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'tag' => 'foo',
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
    )
);

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
    the_title();
    // more stuff here
endwhile;

wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $my_query ) );

wp_reset_postdata();    // avoid errors further down the page
```

So make sure you are passing your custom query object into the `wp_pagenavi()` function call.

~Edit~ 
Here's the link to the documentation: http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/wpn-2-74.html

~Edit 2~
Try this code that has been customized for your particular application:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post__not_in' => $firstPosts,
    'cat' => -23,
);
$loop3 = new WP_Query( $args );
```

...

```
wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $loop3 ) );
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I believe the problem is even with the loop because when I disable the plugin pagenavi , and call a counter of max_num_page, the pager still counts the hidden posts.

        global $wp_query;
        echo $wp_query->max_num_pages;

Comment: I think if you're calling `$wp_query->max_num_pages`, you're getting the total for all posts. That's getting the number of pages for the main loop. What is the output of `$loop3->found_posts`?

Comment: Your solution (edit 2) works for me. The loop stops at the last post.  But there's a problem. I need the "", "", before the array on pagenavi to call the first and last_text link (to go the last page). Any idea? (but thanks, you helped me a lot!)

Comment: If I put $loop3->found_posts, I get the count of all the posts, no exception.

Comment: Are you able to change the first and last link text in the plugin admin? I've never actually used this plugin, but a brief skim of the code makes it look like theres a setting for this in the CMS, so you shouldn't have to pass in those parameters in the funciton. Plus, the wp_pagenavi() function only takes an array of options, it doesn't take two string values and then an array of options.

Comment: Yes, I can. I used the "", "", because I can change the first and last_text link from string to image (svg), making a button. But you gave me an idea. Changing in PageNavi Settings Panel, everything works like a charm. So I'll not use the image ("", "",) anymore and customize at Panel Settings.

Thank you very much. You resolved my problem.

(and sorry my awful English)|

Comment: Thank you! It was my pleasure.